# Number of ways to partition an array of numbers so that the partition sums are equal and first part numbers are lesser than second part

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, dynamic-programming

This question is related to the famous combinatorics question on [TopCoder called Jewelry](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=1166&rd=4705)

You are given an array of numbers :

$\{1,2,3,4,5,5\}$

The task is to count the number of ways that the array can be partitioned keeping in mind the sum of the two partitions must be equal, like-:

$\{1,2\} \{3\}$

I know how to solve this problem if there are no equal elements in the array. But the problem starts when there are equal elements.

The [solution](https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=tco03_online_rd_4) shows that way of counting that is given by the following expression:

```
comb(k,u) * waysAbove[s - v[i]*u] * waysBelow[s];
```

Where `u` is the number of equal items chosen in the first partition?

My question is as follows:

**Why are we only calculating combinations for the first partition? What happens to equal elements picked in the second partition?** Why are they not included?

Please have a look at the links given in the question.

**If the question is not clear please let me know what other information I can include to make it clearer.**

Comment: A term for the sets that make up the *partition* is a *part*.  If you have no objection, I think the title should be edited to say the elements of the *first part* are less than all elements of the *second part*.  I'm a bit unclear as to whether you envision only two parts, or potentially more than two parts but where all part sums being equal.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I only envision two parts, as that is what is given in the question.

Comment: When an array of numbers as you describe it contains duplicate entries, we call this a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) and partitions of multisets are discussed in some previous Questions.  Here the situation is pretty simple in that you have asked only about two parts.  I'm unclear about your condition that "first part numbers are lesser than second part".  This appears in the title, and the example $\{1,2,3\} = \{1,2\} \cup \{3\}$ suggests the interpretation that every element of the first part is less than every element of the second part.  But this is very restrictive.

Comment: If we look for comparison at the coding exercise "Jewelry" that you linked to, the goal is not to "partition" the multiset (array of numbers), but to find a pair of disjoint subsets (of distinguishable items) whose sums of values are equal, and so that the value of each item in the first set is less than *or equal to* the value of each item in the second set.  Not every item needs to be included in one of the two sets (but an item can belong to at most one set).

Comment: @hardmath "the interpretation that every element of the first part is less than every element of the second part" Yes that is exactly what I mean. They can also be equal ie. {3} {3}. And when you say "but to find a pair of disjoint subsets  whose sums of values are equal" - that makes sense, but I have no idea how to do that. Could you please elaborate further, been stuck with this problem for over 4 months.